# Tensorflow - Prepare a CSV file to feed a Recurrent Neural Network

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I have a question. At school we started a new project with Neural Networks and we had to choose what kind of AI we wanted to program. I chose for a Recurrent Neural Network which could predict if a price will be higher or lower after a few periods. I succesfully programmed that and it trained well. But now I want to try a test run, but I don't know how I can prepare a csv file to feed the RNN. This is my trainings code:

```
main_df = pd.DataFrame()

ratios = ["BTC-USD", "LTC-USD", "ETH-USD"]
for ratio in ratios:


    url="https://www.test.nl/get_csv_content.php?method=train&ratio=" + str(ratio)
    dataset = requests.get(url, verify=False).content
    df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(dataset.decode('utf-8')), names=["time", "low", "high", "open", "close", "volume", "rsi14", "ma5", "ema5", "ema12", "ema20", "macd", "signal"])

    df.rename(columns={"close": str(ratio)+"_close", "volume": str(ratio) + "_volume", "rsi14": str(ratio) + "_rsi14", "ma5": str(ratio) + "_ma5", "ema5": str(ratio) + "_ema5", "ema12": str(ratio) + "_ema12", "ema20": str(ratio) + "_ema20", "macd": str(ratio) + "_macd", "signal": str(ratio) + "_signal"}, inplace=True)

    df.set_index("time", inplace=True)
    df = df[[str(ratio) + "_close", str(ratio) + "_volume", str(ratio) + "_rsi14", str(ratio) + "_ma5", str(ratio) + "_ema5", str(ratio) + "_ema12", str(ratio) + "_ema20", str(ratio) + "_macd", str(ratio) + "_signal"]]

    if len(main_df) == 0:
        main_df = df
    else:
        main_df = main_df.join(df)


main_df['future'] = main_df[str(RATIO_TO_PREDICT) + "_close"].shift(-FUTURE_PERIOD_PREDICT)
main_df['target'] = list(map(classify, main_df[str(RATIO_TO_PREDICT) + "_close"], main_df["future"]))
#print(main_df[[str(RATIO_TO_PREDICT) + "_close", "future", "target"]].head(10))


times = sorted(main_df.index.values)
last_5pct = times[-int(0.05*len(times))]

validation_main_df = main_df[(main_df.index >= last_5pct)]
main_df = main_df[(main_df.index < last_5pct)]

train_x, train_y = preprocess_df(main_df)
validation_x, validation_y = preprocess_df(validation_main_df)
```

And here are the functions:

```
#Constant Variables
SEQ_LEN = 30
FUTURE_PERIOD_PREDICT = 3
RATIO_TO_PREDICT = "LTC-USD"
EPOCHS = 10
BATCH_SIZE = 64
NAME = str(RATIO_TO_PREDICT) + "-" + str(SEQ_LEN) + "-SEQ-" + str(FUTURE_PERIOD_PREDICT) + "-PRED-" + str(int(time.time()))

def classify(current, future):
    if float(future) > float(current):
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

def preprocess_df(df):
    df = df.drop('future', 1)

    for col in df.columns:
        if col != "target":
            df[col] = df[col].pct_change()
            df.dropna(inplace=True)
            df[col] = preprocessing.scale(df[col].values)

    df.dropna(inplace=True)

    sequential_data = []
    prev_days = deque(maxlen=SEQ_LEN)



    for i in df.values:
        prev_days.append([n for n in i[:-1]])
        if len(prev_days) == SEQ_LEN:
            sequential_data.append([np.array(prev_days), i[-1]])

    random.shuffle(sequential_data)

    buys = []
    sells = []

    for seq, target in sequential_data:
        if target == 0:
            sells.append([seq, target])
        elif target == 1:
            buys.append([seq, target])


    random.shuffle(buys)
    random.shuffle(sells)

    lower = min(len(buys), len(sells))


    buys = buys[:lower]
    sells = sells[:lower]


    sequential_data = buys+sells

    random.shuffle(sequential_data)

    x = []
    y = []

    for seq, target in sequential_data:
        x.append(seq)
        y.append(target)

    return np.array(x), y
```

Now my question is: After I trained the model, how can I prepare a new CSV file in the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, to test your model, you would select a subset of your original dataset, and set it aside for testing purposes *only*. That is, you would not use that data for training at all.

Now, the link that you're using in your code to fetch CSV files from a remote server does not work for me, but it does have a query param, `?method=train`, which you could presumably change to something like `?method=test` to fetch the testing dataset, and use that for your trial run. Failing that, you could just set aside 20% of your dataset for testing, and use the rest for training.

Comment: Okay, but how the input in the model must be an array. So, how do I need to use the def preprocess_df(df) again and than use test_x instead of train_x?

Comment: I've picked 12,5% for training. When I change the ?method to test, I get a whole new CSV file. And that CSV file is for testing, but again: "Do I need to use the def preprocess_df(df) again?"

Comment: @Vreesie, if you are receiving a separate file for testing purposes only, then there's no need to partition your original training dataset. Also, now that you have your testing dataset, you should preprocess it in the exact same way as your training dataset, and then evaluating it against your model trained with the training CSV.